# horizontal Linear Layout inside horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout

layout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/itemlistbg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

 </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am adding children to linear layout id `itemlist` dynamically. if items are too many then result is ok. But if there is 2 items in list then linear layout `itemlist` leaves a space at the end. `this only happens on big screen devices`.

[image: eclipse preview of xml]

Comment: image is eclipse preview of xml.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to change your scrollview like this.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/itemlistbg"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you for the answer....but i change the visibility of `itemlist` layout to `GONE` if there is empty list on run time. That makes application to show only background image of scroll view.

Comment: Why do you not set your visibility control to `HorizontalScrollView`?

Comment: i don't want it this. But now i think i have to do this way,no option.
Well, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `android:layout_weight` ?

Comment: tried it, it says `Invalid layout param in a HorizontalScrollView: layout_weight`.